# AMSsymb in ConTeXt

Tags: amsmath, context, amssymb

Where can I find some of the functionality, namely the symbols, from the LaTeX package AMSSymb in ConTeXt? For example, how do I place a `\blacksquare`? Is there an equivalent in ConTeXt? I didn't find what I am looking for at [contextgarden](http://contextgarden.net/).

Comment: edited to correct package name; amssym is for ams-tex, not latex. the latex package is named amssymb.  but can't help with context; sorry.

Comment: Are you using MkII (pdftex) or MkIV (luatex)?  The amssymb glyphs are supported and in most cases `$\glyphname$` should work. For some of the glyphs, the names are changed. For MkII you can get a list of all the glyphs using `\showmathcharacters`. In particular, `\blacksquare` is supported. For MkIV, see the list of alll the supported glyphs using `\ShowCompleteFont` from `s-fnt-10` module. See `s-fnt-10.tex` for details. For `\blacksquare` you need a open type math font (like xits), but there is a bug in the mappings (at the ConTeXt end) and `\blacksquare` is mapped to the wrong symbol.

Comment: @barbara: which unicode slot should `\blacksquare` correspond to: 2FA0, 25AA, 25FC, 25FE, 2B1B, 2B1D?

Comment: @aditya -- my interpretation has been that `\blacksquare` corresponds to unicode 2FA0.  the relative sizes of the various squares (and other geometric symbols) can be found on p.20 of [unicode technical report 25 on mathematics](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr25/).  some of these don't yet have "established" tex command names.  i prepared a table for the stix project with tex names (either already recognized or proposed) for all unicode math symbols, but it still needs some adjustments as a result of decisions made during the final stix font cleanup.

Comment: Thanks. I'll fix the mapping in ConTeXt (and, at some stage, coordinate with @Will Robertson to use the same mappings for ConTeXt and unicode-math).

Comment: @Aditya Perhaps you could turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: "I prepared a table for the STIX project with TeX names" Can I ask whether your table is available?

Comment: @morbusg -- the (rather old version of the) table is linked from [the ams stix project home page](http://www.ams.org/STIX).  as mentioned earlier, some changes (and additions) have been made since that version of the table was posted, but the bulk of the core remains valid; that is, anything with a code in unicode plane 0 should be reliable, and all but a few tex names will remain unchanged.  updating the table (which *is* on my to-do list) requires extensive checking of the symbols assigned to the private use area, where the id-codes originally assigned were re-used with different meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\blacksquare` works in ConTeXt out of the box. To see a list of all supported symbols, you can use (in MkIV)

```
\usemodule[mat-11]
\usemodule[cambria]
\starttext
\showmathfontcharacters
\stoptext
```

which gives a listing of all Unicode characters in a font, and the corresponding ConTeXt name for the character (look for mathname).